# Speed decrease in subsetting `data.table` when adding a bracket

Tags: r, data.table

I recently noticed in some old code that I had been including extra square brackets when subsetting a `data.table` and performing a function repeatedly (in my case, calculating correlation matrices). So,

```
# Slow way
rcorr(DT[subgroup][, !'Group', with=F])

# Faster way
rcorr(DT[subgroup, !'Group', with=F])
```

(The difference being after `subgroup`). Just out of curiosity, why does this occur? With the extra brackets, does `data.table` have to perform some extra computations?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27520688/559784) should be of some help, in addition to Richard's nice answer.

Comment: Absolutely! That was an extremely helpful answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple interpretation:

```
# Slow way
rcorr(DT[subgroup][, !'Group'])
```

The second set of brackets is a second operation on `DT`, meaning that `DT[subgroup]` creates a new data table from `DT`, and then `[, !'Group']` operates on that data table, creating another new data table. Hence the decline in speed.

```
# Faster way
rcorr(DT[subgroup, !'Group'])
```

This way operates only on `DT`, all in one go.

Comment: Thanks! I figured something like that was going on.

Comment: @Chris, it works on the same premise that `[` would in base R, if that helps