# Delete rows one at a time without expanding memory in R

Tags: r

```
testd <- data.frame(A= c(1,2,3,4), B = c(5,6,7,8), C= c(3,4,5,9) )
```

I would like to remove rows where
data$A * data$B * data$C > 105.

I could solve this for example using `ifelse`, create a fourth column and delete afterwards. The problem is that my file is almost taking up all memory and I can't proceed. Is it possible to row by row using `apply` function?

```
rowf <- function(x){
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
 ans1 <- x$A * x$B * x$C

 if(ans1 > 105){

   return(NULL)
 }

else {

  return(x)
}

}

apply(testd,1, rowf)
```

The above is my try on this, but I cant succeed.

Comment: I'm guessing that `apply` will save result in a new object

Comment: Have you tried something like `dplyr::filter(testd, A * B * C <= 105)`?

Comment: I would suggest working on half the dataset until it fits in memory with comfortable margins

Comment: `apply` will coerce to a matrix for the calculation and use *more* memory - as well as creating a copy. Use `data.table`.

Comment: ``dplyr``, specially its ``filter`` command tends to be slower and use up more memory than the equivalent ``data.table`` command (this may have changed with the latest ``dplyr`` release). Try ``DT[DT $A * DT $B * DT $C <= 105]``. [See this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27520688/5278205) for more on the topic.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian each of your Boolean expressions will create a temporary Boolean vector, JFI

Comment: @David Arenburg ahh I see, that would add to memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using subsetting:

```
testd <- testd[(testd$A*testd$B*testd$C)<105,]
```