# Filter operation on rows returns a data frame not data table

Tags: r, filter, data.table, dplyr

I noticed that when I used the following to subset the data, it returns a data frame.

```
   dplyr::filter(DT,cond)
```

I can always convert it back to a data table, but I am curious why it returns a data frame and if there is a way to keep all data in a data table format.
Here is an example

```
    irisDT <- as.data.table(iris)
    class(irisDT)
    filteredIrisDT <- dplyr::filter(irisDT, Sepal.Length >7)
    class(filteredIrisDT)
```

`class(iristDT)` returns as a

```
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

whereas `class(filteredIrisDT)` returns

```
[1] "data.frame"
```

Trying to make my code more streamlined and less verbose.

Comment: Look at the package `dtplyr`. It will return objects in data.table. Load both the packages and use your `dplyr` functions. Other way to do this will be `irisDT[Sepal.Length > 7]`

Comment: to add on: despite `dtplyr` + `dplyr::filter` preserving the class of `irisDT`, you don't get the full performance benefits of using `data.table` this way.  `irisDT[Sepal.Length > 7]` will perform better

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511604/dplyr-on-data-table-am-i-really-using-data-table

Comment: I would proceed with caution on using dtplyr if you have coded with dplyr.  It causes many issues with my previous code.  Best to start off using dtplyr rather than start using it half way through a project.  Now that I know it exists, I will use it on my next major project, but I will need to rework some functions I have currently written.  The problem is any dplyr calls will return a data table which I am not always expecting.  Great example of watching data types and understanding their respective nuances!

Answer (score -1):

If you are only looking to subset the data you can use **subset** function in R.

```
filteredIrisDT <- subset(irisDT, Sepal.Length >7)
```