# data.table vs dplyr memory use revisited

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I know that **data.table** vs **dplyr** comparisons are a perennial favourite on SO. (Full disclosure: I like and use both packages.)

However, in trying to provide some comparisons for a class that I'm teaching, I ran into something surprising w.r.t. memory usage. My expectation was that **dplyr** would perform especially poorly with operations that require (implicit) filtering or slicing of data. But that's not what I'm finding. Compare:

First **dplyr**.

```r
library(bench)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(123)

DF = tibble(x = rep(1:10, times = 1e5),
                y = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10e5, replace = TRUE),
                z = rnorm(1e6))

DF %>% filter(x > 7) %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(mean(z))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    y     `mean(z)`
#>  * <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 A     -0.00336 
#>  2 B     -0.00702 
#>  3 C      0.00291 
#>  4 D     -0.00430 
#>  5 E     -0.00705 
#>  6 F     -0.00568 
#>  7 G     -0.00344 
#>  8 H      0.000553
#>  9 I     -0.00168 
#> 10 J      0.00661

bench::bench_process_memory()
#> current     max 
#>   585MB   611MB
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Then **data.table**.

```r
library(bench)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(123)

DT = data.table(x = rep(1:10, times = 1e5),
                y = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10e5, replace = TRUE),
                z = rnorm(1e6))

DT[x > 7, mean(z), by = y]
#>     y            V1
#>  1: F -0.0056834238
#>  2: I -0.0016755202
#>  3: J  0.0066061660
#>  4: G -0.0034436348
#>  5: B -0.0070242788
#>  6: E -0.0070462070
#>  7: H  0.0005525803
#>  8: D -0.0043024627
#>  9: A -0.0033609302
#> 10: C  0.0029146372

bench::bench_process_memory()
#>  current      max 
#> 948.47MB   1.17GB
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So, basically **data.table** appears to be using nearly *twice* the memory that **dplyr** does for this simple filtering+grouping operation. Note that I'm essentially replicating a use-case that @Arun suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511604/dplyr-on-data-table-am-i-really-using-data-table/27520688#27520688) would be much more memory efficient on the data.table side. (**data.table** is still a lot faster, though.)

Any ideas, or am I just missing something obvious?

P.S. As an aside, comparing memory usage ends up being more complicated than it first seems because R's standard memory profiling tools (Rprofmem and co.) all [ignore](https://twitter.com/BrodieGaslam/status/1182838341072576512)  operations that occur outside R (e.g. calls to the C++ stack). Luckily, the **bench** package now provides a [`bench_process_memory()`](http://bench.r-lib.org/reference/bench_process_memory.html) function that also tracks memory outside of R’s GC heap, which is why I use it here.

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Arch Linux
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.9.so
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] data.table_1.12.8 dplyr_0.8.99.9002 bench_1.1.1.9000 
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      knitr_1.28        magrittr_1.5      tidyselect_1.0.0 
#>  [5] R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.5.9000  stringr_1.4.0     highr_0.8        
#>  [9] tools_3.6.3       xfun_0.13         htmltools_0.4.0   ellipsis_0.3.0   
#> [13] yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.25     tibble_3.0.1      lifecycle_0.2.0  
#> [17] crayon_1.3.4      purrr_0.3.4       vctrs_0.2.99.9011 glue_1.4.0       
#> [21] evaluate_0.14     rmarkdown_2.1     stringi_1.4.6     compiler_3.6.3   
#> [25] pillar_1.4.3      generics_0.0.2    pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am glad to see this new `bench_process_memory`! You can find some extra info about memory usage in one of my slides https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/r-talks/2019-06-18_Poznan_why-data.table/why-data.table.pdf

Comment: Are you able to try recent dplyr? AFAIK they have rewritten groupby

Comment: Thanks @jangorecki, very helpful! To answer the latter question first, yes I am using the latest dev version of dplyr. That being said, I just re-did the memory evaluation using `cgmemtime` as per your slide suggestions and now the numbers are slightly in favour of data.table. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Following @jangorecki's suggestion, I redid the analysis using the [cgmemtime](https://github.com/gsauthof/cgmemtime) shell utility. The numbers are far closer — even with multithreading enabled — and data.table now edges out dplyr w.r.t to .high-water RSS+CACHE memory usage.

**dplyr**

```sh
$ ./cgmemtime Rscript ~/mem-comp-dplyr.R
Child user:    0.526 s
Child sys :    0.033 s
Child wall:    0.455 s
Child high-water RSS                    :     128952 KiB
Recursive and acc. high-water RSS+CACHE :     118516 KiB
```

**data.table**

```sh
$ ./cgmemtime Rscript ~/mem-comp-dt.R
Child user:    0.510 s
Child sys :    0.056 s
Child wall:    0.464 s
Child high-water RSS                    :     129032 KiB
Recursive and acc. high-water RSS+CACHE :     118320 KiB
```

Bottom line: Accurately measuring memory usage from within R [is](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-R-apparently-not-releasing-memory_003f) [complicated](https://twitter.com/jimhester_/status/1182934355141898245).

I'll leave my original answer below because I think it still has value.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Okay, so in the process of writing this out I realised that **data.table**'s default multi-threading behaviour appears to be the major culprit. If I re-run the latter chunk, but this time turn of multi-threading, the two results are much more comparable:

```r
library(bench)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(123)
setDTthreads(1) ## TURN OFF MULTITHREADING

DT = data.table(x = rep(1:10, times = 1e5),
                y = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10e5, replace = TRUE),
                z = rnorm(1e6))

DT[x > 7, mean(z), by = y]
#>     y            V1
#>  1: F -0.0056834238
#>  2: I -0.0016755202
#>  3: J  0.0066061660
#>  4: G -0.0034436348
#>  5: B -0.0070242788
#>  6: E -0.0070462070
#>  7: H  0.0005525803
#>  8: D -0.0043024627
#>  9: A -0.0033609302
#> 10: C  0.0029146372

bench::bench_process_memory()
#> current     max 
#>   589MB   612MB
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Still, I'm surprised that they're this close. The **data.table** memory performance actually gets comparably worse if I try with a larger data set — despite using a single thread — which makes me suspicious that I'm still not measuring memory usage correctly...