# How to chain together a mix of data.table and base r functions?

Tags: r, data.table, operators, chaining

I am using the data.table package to work with a very large data set, and value it's speed and clarity. But I am new to it and am having difficulties chaining functions together especially when working with a mixed set of data.table and base R functions. My question is, how do I chain together the below example functions, into one seamless string of code for defining the target `data` object?

Below is the correct output, generated by running each line of code separately (unchained) with the generating code shown immediately beneath the output:

```
> data
    ID Period State Values
 1:  1      1    X0      5
 2:  1      2    X1      0
 3:  1      3    X2      0
 4:  1      4    X1      0
 5:  2      1    X0      1
 6:  2      2    XX      0
 7:  2      3    XX      0
 8:  2      4    XX      0
 9:  3      1    X2      0
10:  3      2    X1      0
11:  3      3    X9      0
12:  3      4    X3      0
13:  4      1    X2      1
14:  4      2    X1      2
15:  4      3    X9      3
16:  4      4    XX      0

library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    Values_1 = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    Values_2 = c(5, 2, 0, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X1","X0","X2","X0","X0", "X2","X1","X9","X3", "X2","X1","X9","X3")
  )

# changes State to "XX" if remaining Values_1 + Values_2 cumulative sums = 0 for each ID: 
setDT(data)[, State := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))), State, "XX"), ID]

# create new column "Values", which equals "Values_1":
setDT(data)[,Values := Values_1] 

# in base R, drops columns Values_1 and Values_2:
data <- subset(data, select = -c(Values_1,Values_2)) # How to do this step in data.table, if possible or advisable?  

# in base R, changes all "XX" elements in State column to "HI":
data$State <- gsub('XX','HI', data$State) # How to do this step in data.table, if possible or advisable?
```

For what it's worth, below is my attempt to chain together using '%>%' pipe operators, which fails (error message *Error in data$State : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable*), and though I'd rather chain together using data.table operators:

```
data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    Values_1 = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    Values_2 = c(5, 2, 0, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X1","X0","X2","X0","X0", "X2","X1","X9","X3", "X2","X1","X9","X3")
  ) %>%
  setDT(data)[, State := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))), State, "XX"), ID] %>%
  setDT(data)[,Values := Values_1] %>%
  subset(data, select = -c(Values_1,Values_2)) %>%
  data$State <- gsub('XX','HI', data$State)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to

- rename column `Value_1` to `Value` (or in OP's words: *create new column "Values", which equals "Values_1"*)
- drop column `Value_2`
- replace all occurrences of `XX` by `HI` in column `State`

Here is what I would do in data.table syntax:

```
setDT(data)[, State := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))), State, "XX"), ID][
  , Values_2 := NULL][
    State == "XX", State := "HI"][]
setnames(data, "Values_1", "Values")
data
```

> ```
>        ID Period Values  State
>  1:     1      1      5     X0
>  2:     1      2      0     X1
>  3:     1      3      0     X2
>  4:     1      4      0     X1
>  5:     2      1      1     X0
>  6:     2      2      0     HI
>  7:     2      3      0     HI
>  8:     2      4      0     HI
>  9:     3      1      0     X2
> 10:     3      2      0     X1
> 11:     3      3      0     X9
> 12:     3      4      0     X3
> 13:     4      1      1     X2
> 14:     4      2      2     X1
> 15:     4      3      3     X9
> 16:     4      4      0     HI
> ```

`setnames()` updates *by reference*, e.g., without copying. There is no need to create a copy of `Values_1` and delete `Values_1` later on.

Also, `[State == "XX", State := "HI"]` replaces `XX` by `HI` *only in affected rows* by reference while
`[, State := gsub('XX','HI', State)]` replaces the whole column.

data.table chaining is used where appropriate.

BTW: I wonder why the replacement of `XX` by `HI` cannot be done rightaway in the first statement:

```
setDT(data)[, State := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))), State, "HI"), ID][
  , Values_2 := NULL][]
setnames(data, "Values_1", "Values")
```

Comment: Given the size of data files I'm working with, I'm going to spend time learning more about data.table and will need to convert a lot of my code from base R/dplyr to data.table. I've been running the above solutions against the full data set, and speed checking, and the speed boost offered by data.table is significant

Comment: Some years ago, before the advent of the *tidyverse* was heralded, I decided to start with `data.table`. I prefer the concise, SQL-like syntax, the outstanding join features, *updates by reference*, and many handy functions like `rowid()`, `rleid()`, `fread()`, e.g. Speed and low memory footprint come as bonus.

Comment: However, if speed is a concern to you, @CuriousJorge-user9788072, you may have a look at the [`collapse` package](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/) which seems to be even faster than `data.table`. I have no experience with it, yet, but if have seen some answers on SO where `collapse` has a speed advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You can just chain using bracket notation `[`. That way you only need to call `setDT()` once, as you are continuing all operations in the `data.table` universe, so `data` does not stop being a `data.table`. Also `setDT()` modifies in place, so it does not need assignment (although by piping to it its return value is being assigned to `data` which is fine, too).

First define the data and make it a `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
data <-
    data.frame(
        ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
        Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
        Values_1 = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0),
        Values_2 = c(5, 2, 0, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0),
        State = c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X0", "X2", "X0", "X0", "X2", "X1", "X9", "X3", "X2", "X1", "X9", "X3")
    ) |>
    setDT()
```

Then define the columns you need. Note the functional notation to [apply a function on several columns](https://atrebas.github.io/post/2020-06-17-datatable-introduction/#computation-on-columns).

```r
data[, `:=`(
    State = ifelse(
        rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))),
        State, "XX"
    )
),
by = ID
][
    ,
    `:=`(
        Values = Values_1,
        Values_1 = NULL,
        Values_2 = NULL,
        State = gsub("XX", "HI", State)
    )
]
```

Output:

```r
data
#     ID Period State Values
#  1:  1      1    X0      5
#  2:  1      2    X1      0
#  3:  1      3    X2      0
#  4:  1      4    X1      0
#  5:  2      1    X0      1
#  6:  2      2    HI      0
#  7:  2      3    HI      0
#  8:  2      4    HI      0
#  9:  3      1    X2      0
# 10:  3      2    X1      0
# 11:  3      3    X9      0
# 12:  3      4    X3      0
# 13:  4      1    X2      1
# 14:  4      2    X1      2
# 15:  4      3    X9      3
# 16:  4      4    HI      0
```

You may want to read further about [chaining commands in data.table](https://atrebas.github.io/post/2020-06-17-datatable-introduction/#chaining-commands). I think that page is an excellent summary of the syntax and features of the package and is worth reading in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `magrittr` package to chaining data.tables using `.` before `[`. Try the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    Values_1 = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    Values_2 = c(5, 2, 0, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X1","X0","X2","X0","X0", "X2","X1","X9","X3", "X2","X1","X9","X3")
  ) %>% 
  setDT(data) %>%
  .[, State := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))), State, "XX"), ID] %>%
  .[,Values := Values_1] %>%
  select(-c(Values_1, Values_2)) %>%
  mutate(State = gsub('XX','HI', State))
```

Output:

```
   rn ID Period State Values
 1:  1  1      1    X0      5
 2:  2  1      2    X1      0
 3:  3  1      3    X2      0
 4:  4  1      4    X1      0
 5:  5  2      1    X0      1
 6:  6  2      2    HI      0
 7:  7  2      3    HI      0
 8:  8  2      4    HI      0
 9:  9  3      1    X2      0
10: 10  3      2    X1      0
11: 11  3      3    X9      0
12: 12  3      4    X3      0
13: 13  4      1    X2      1
14: 14  4      2    X1      2
15: 15  4      3    X9      3
16: 16  4      4    HI      0
```

Comment: Do you need to add a `library(dplyr)` here for your `select()` and `mutate()` calls? Also [in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511604/dplyr-on-data-table-am-i-really-using-data-table) I think using `dplyr` verbs on `data.table` objects is less memory efficient than using the `data.table` equivalents, although in this particular case the difference will be negligible and perhaps your code answers the specific question about chaining with the pipe slightly more.

Comment: @SamR, you are right that `dplyr` is necessary. I think the main point of this question is to use the `data.table` functions in one chain using `%>%`.