# Remove duplicates by keeping row with higher value in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicates (in one column) from this data frame. Please take a look on column `Name` and there u can find duplicates:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 21, 21, 22.8, 21.4
), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6), disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 
                                             160, 160, 108, 258), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 110, 110, 93, 
                                                                         110), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08), wt = c(2.62, 
                                                                                                                                            2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215), qsec = c(17.66, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    17.02, 19.61, 19.84, 16.46, 17.82, 18.61, 19.44), vs = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), am = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), gear = c(4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3), carb = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1), Name = c("Mazda RX4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Mazda RX4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive")), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Mazda RX41", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Mazda RX4 Wag1", "Datsun 7101", "Hornet 4 Drive1"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to keep the row which has for the same `Name` higher value in column `qsec`.

Any ideas ? It might also be situation that there are more than two rows with the same `Name` and even number in `qsec` might be the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
dplyr::filter(data, qsec == max(qsec), .by = Name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Esssentially, split the data frame by `Name` and keep the row where `qsec == max(qsec)`. You can do this in base R, `dplyr` or `data.table`.

#### base R

Here's a base R approach. It requires at least R 4.2 for the use of `_` in the final pipe.

```r
dat |>
    split(~Name) |>
    lapply(\(df) df[df$qsec == max(df$qsec), ]) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _)

#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb           Name
# Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 19.61  1  1    4    1     Datsun 710
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.84  1  0    3    1 Hornet 4 Drive
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 17.66  0  1    4    4      Mazda RX4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.82  0  1    4    4  Mazda RX4 Wag
```

Note: if there are ties, this will return *all* the rows with the max value of `qsec`. If you want to return one row, instead use `lapply(\(df) df[which.max(df$qsec), ])`, which will return the first row with the max value.

#### `dplyr` approach

Alternatively, you can use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat  |>
    group_by(Name)  |>
    slice_max(qsec) |>
    ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 × 12
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb Name          
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
# 1  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  19.6     1     1     4     1 Datsun 710    
# 2  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.8     1     0     3     1 Hornet 4 Drive
# 3  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  17.7     0     1     4     4 Mazda RX4     
# 4  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.8     0     1     4     4 Mazda RX4 Wag
```

Similarly this will return all rows with the max value.  If you want to return only one row you can instead use `slice_max(qsec, with_ties = FALSE, n = 1)`. For more options, see the `slice_max()` [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html).

#### `data.table`

If your data is large this may be quicker than the other methods.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[dat[, .I[qsec == max(qsec)], by=Name]$V1]
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb           Name
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>         <char>
# 1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 17.66     0     1     4     4      Mazda RX4
# 2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.82     0     1     4     4  Mazda RX4 Wag
# 3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 19.61     1     1     4     1     Datsun 710
# 4:  21.4     6   258   110  3.08 3.215 19.84     1     0     3     1 Hornet 4 Drive
```

Alternatively, just for the first max value, you can use:

```r
dat[dat[, .I[which.max(qsec)], by=Name]$V1]
# same output in this case
```

Comment: the dplyr one can be `slice_max(data, qsec, by =  Name)` :-)

Comment: @Mark fair point re `ungroup()`. Though it works, I don't much like `by = Name` in `slice_max()`. As Hadley Wickham himself [said on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511604/dplyr-on-data-table-am-i-really-using-data-table/27520688#comment43492306_27520688), _I like that_ `group_by()` _is a separate operation in dplyr. It fundamentally changes the computation so I think should be obvious when skimming the code, and it's easier to spot_ `group_by()` _than the_ `by` _argument to_ `[.data.table`. I don't know why they changed the API but I prefer the more verbose approach.

Comment: @Mark sorry wrong link! I wish it was possible to edit comments for longer than 5 minutes. It's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27840349/12545041) answer by Hadley Wickham that contains that quote.